# Given two arrays with same size, find the couple of elements from both arrays that make sum with the smallest absolute value

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I was tasked with this problem yesterday, and since then was trying to find a efficient solution for it.
The detail of the solution is: Given two arrays a[n], b[n], find a pair (a[i],b[j]) so that abs(a[i]+b[j]) is as small as possible. The two array consist of integer elements not greater than 1 billion, and n here is at most 10000.
I know that a solution consist of two for loops here is impractical since the arrays sizes are less or equal to 10000.
I am thinking of a solution where I will sort these elements in a manner, which I haven't found out yet, so that we can easily identified the sum which has the least absolute value, since my class is learning about sorting algorithms.
Can you help me figure out the manner here.
PS: Sorry, I can't type the mathematics symbols here.

Comment: i presume the elements are integers?

Comment: Are you required to find the two elements with the smallest sum? That's how I understand it.

Comment: Isn't it just the min(array_1)+ min(array_2) ?

Comment: Can you please describe the problem more detailed (understandable) and add some demo data

Comment: Do you want to maximize `|a + b|` where `a` is from the first array and `b` is from the second array?

Comment: @pkacprzak Actually, minimize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a `Python` code that solves the problem in `O(nlogn + mlogm) + O(m+n)` = `O(nlogn + mlogm)` time, where `n` is the length of the first array and `m` is the length of the second array. Here is the code:

```
arr1.sort()
arr2.sort(reverse = True)
n = len(arr1)
m = len(arr2)
print arr1
print arr2
minim = abs(arr1[0] + arr2[0])

i = 0
j = 0

while i<n and j<m:
   minimum = abs(arr1[i] + arr2[j])
   minim = min(minim,minimum)
   if arr1[i]>0 and arr2[j]>0:
      j += 1
   elif arr1[i]<=0 and arr2[j]<=0:
      i += 1
   elif arr1[i]>0 and arr2[j]<=0:
      if abs(arr1[i]) > abs(arr2[j]):
          j += 1
      else:
          i += 1
   elif arr1[i]<=0 and arr2[j]>0:
      if abs(arr1[i]) > abs(arr2[j]):
          i += 1
      else:
          j += 1

print minim
```

**Example:**

`arr1[] = [-23, -10, 30, 44, 45]`

`arr2[] = [61, 55, 32, 22, -55]`

Answer: `1`

Answer (score 0):

You could negate one of the lists and sort this together with the other list. In this new list you look for two consecutive entries with the smallest distance and such that the two entries are one from each original list.

If `a[i], i=0,1,...,n` is the first and `b[j], j=0,1,...,n` is hthe second, then `min(|a[k]+b[l]|)=min(|a[k]-(-b[l])|)`. So instead of minimizing the sum of `a[k]` and `b[l]` for some `k,l` we can minimize the difference between `a[k]` and `-b[l]` for some `k,l`. So we look for a pair `a[k]`, `-b[l]` as close together as possible. Such a pair must be consecutive in a list obtained from sorting `a[i], -b[j]` for `i,j=0,1,...,n` into a single list `c[t]` of length `2n`.

Sorting `c` is O(n log n), running through `c` is O(n), so the running time is dominated by sorting.

Comment: what if no consecutive numbers are present such that one of the numbers is from array1 and the other from array2??

Comment: @User_Targaryen This cannot happen, as the combined list is linearly ordered. If the smallest entry in the combined list array3 obtained from sorting array1 and -array2 is from he first array, then the smallest entry from -array2 must appear at some index i>0. Then array3[i-1] and array3[i] is a pair of consecutive entries, one from array1 and one from array2. A similar argument works it the smallest entry in array3 is from -array2. This pair doesn't need to be the one with the smallest distance, however.

Comment: Let `a=[1,2,3,4,5]` and `b=[6,7,8]`, so final answer = 1. By your method, your third array will look like `[-8,-7,-6,1,2,3,4,5]`. Now, how will you find the answer as `1` by your method? Please explain

Comment: @User_Targaryen How do you get  `1` as a sum of an element of `a` and `b`?

Comment: @User_Targaryen No. The OP asks for `min(abs(a[i]+b[j]))`, which is `1+6=7` in your example.

Comment: Sorry.. My bad.. So how will your algorithm get the answer as `7`?? after the final merged sorted array is as the one in my previous comment

Comment: I understood your algorithm. Thanks for being patient!!!! It requires O(n) extra space for the third array and O(n) space to keep track of which element is from which list!!